# Make an entire <li> element clickable, but don't trigger the link when clicking inside links

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I've been looking for a solution the last few days, I didn't really found exactly what I'm looking for.

I have something like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="http://www.link.com" class="li-url"></a>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      Lorem ipsum dolor <a href="http://www.something.com">Something</a>. Etc, blah blah.
   </li>
</ul>
```

What I need:

- Click on the LI element: Go to www.link.com
- Click on "Something" inside the LI: Go to www.something.com (And DON'T go to www.link.com)

(And I don't know if it's possible, but it would be great if I could click on the LI element and if I'm holding my "alt" key on my keyboard, the link would open in a new tab... like any other link. But I don't know if that's possible)

Comment: You want to have *one* link *inside* another link? That would make for a confusing UI, I imagine. And I don't think this is, strictly, possible with CSS (unless you want to wrap each individual element in turn with links).

Comment: The first link doesn't really show up because it has no text.  You could also put the link as an attribute of the LI, but the solution I gave works for the HTML provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may also be interested in `event.stopPropagation()`. Which will allow you to prevent the event from bubbling up (aka notifying the `li` of the click).

```
$('ul > li').click(function(e) {
    // Go to link.com
}).children('a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // Go to something.com
});
```

[​http://jsfiddle.net/erF3S/](http://jsfiddle.net/erF3S/)

Comment: It seems it's not working. When I click on the "li" it doesn't goes to link.com

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you knew a little Javascript. Add `window.location = "ADDRESSHERE";` in place of my comments. Replace ADDRESSHERE with the website URL you want it ot go to.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way.  Tested on jsfiddle.net and it worked for me.

```
$('li').click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find(':first-child').attr('href');
});​​​​​​​​​
```

As far as the alt key goes, I'm not sure that's possible.  I'd let the user decide if they want to open a link in a new tab/window anyway.

Comment: If you post the link to jsFiddle it tends to be considered a good thing. +1

Comment: Thanks Gregg. That work's just fine, except that when I click in "something", it also goes to link.com. (you can see that if you alt+click, the new tab would go to your click something.com, but the current tab goes to link.com)

Comment: why .find(':first-child') and not .find('a')  ?