# Avoid go to link of block element while clicking on link inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a LI element whith a link, and other links inside.

It would be something like this:

jQuery:

```
$('li').click(function() {
   window.location = $(this).children('a.li-url').attr('href');
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.link.com" class="li-url"></a>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor <a href="http://www.something.com">Something</a>. Etc, blah blah.
    </li>
</ul>​
```

The problem is that when I click on "something", It also loads www.link.com (you can see this if you alt+click the something link. It will load something.com in a new tab while loading link.com in your current tab.)

I need to ONLY load something.com when I click on "something"..

Thanks!

Comment: I think you already asked this 1 hour ago http://stackoverflow.com/q/3859918/459897

Comment: why do you have a javascript function anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('li').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'li') {
        window.location = $(this).children('a.li-url').attr('href');
    }
});​
```

## [crazy demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fjRdg/)

---

<sub>Welcome to [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com)</sub>
<sub>Don't forget to accept an answer</sub>

Comment: Thanks! That works. Do you know if it's possible to make possible to load the LI link in a new tab by alt+click, like a normal link?

Answer (score 1):

Add this bit of JS.

```
$('li a:not(.li-url)').click(function() {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
​
```

Using my selector or something else to target the other link within the `li`.

Answer (score -1):

try 
this.preventDefault();

Comment: THANK YOU! That works perfect. One last thing, it would be possible to make possible to load the LI link in a new tab by alt+click, like a normal link?

Comment: Sorry, that preventDefault also broke the LI link... So, doesn't works just fine.

Comment: That's not what preventDefault() will do.

Comment: sorry , i mean stopPropagation() , but typed preventDefault(). anyway you got the answer from others.